# What are the common reasons for an Android app update installation to fail in user devices?

Tags: java, android, google-play

A portion of the users of the app in questions reported installation issues, when they click to install the update the process starts but it does not finish successfully.

Here is a summary of what changed between these versions:

- Version code was the same, but the build number was incremented
- One activity was changed to include the tag `android:launchMode="singleTop"`
- Replaced the deprecated `fill_parent` with `match_parent`
- Replaced `android:gravity="right"` for `android:gravity="end"`
- Replaced `android:gravity="left"` for `android:gravity="start"`
- Added `android:layout_marginStart` and `android:layout_marginEnd` where applicable

Is any of these changes known to cause installation issues in user devices? Any tip is greatly appreciated, because I do not understand how minor changes like these could lead to such issues. I've even halted the release roll-out in order to figure this out.

**Update 1:** I was able to reproduce one error in a test device, the error code is 944. What commonly causes this error?

Comment: Did you generate a new signing key ?

Comment: No. But I did switch my development machine, I used linux before but now I switched to MacOS. As far as I know that shouldn't make a difference, but I will double check everything.

Comment: Copy the debug key from your old machine to your new one and rebuild with it. The file can be found in ~/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood what happened, and it does not seem to be something caused by the app code.

I did some digging after finally seeing the error code and it turns out that error code 944 is caused by the fact that the Play Store servers are offline and can't answer the user's request.

Sources:

1. [Android Authority](https://www.androidauthority.com/play-store-error-codes-705014/)
2. [Android Pit](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-solve-google-play-store-errors#nine-four-four)